# Qsort struct of strings

Tags: c, string, struct, qsort

please, could you help me with qsort of struct of strings? 
I need to sort alphabeticaly words in dictionary. Problem is, that it throws me Segmentation fault...
Here are my structs:

```
typedef struct {
    int length;
    char *data;
} Word;

typedef struct {
    int length;
    int index;
    Word *data;
} Dictionary;
```

Here is compare function:

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) 
{ 
    return strcmp (((Word *)a)->data, ((Word *)b)->data);
}
```

And here is qsort implementation:

```
qsort(&dictionary, dictionary.index, sizeof (Word *), compare);
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Explain the use of `length` and `index` in `Dictionary`.

Comment: length is max length of dictionary and index is actual length

Comment: this qsort parameter: sizeof (Word *) is not correct, you do not want the size of a pointer, you want the size of the word struct.  I.E. sizeof (Word ).  There also seems to be something wrong with the first couple of parameters to qsort, but I'm not sure just what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to `qsort` your dictionary structure rather than the dictionaries data.

```
qsort(dictionary.data, dictionary.index, sizeof (Word *), compare);
```

You should also double check to make sure `dictionary.index` is the length of the dictionary and not `dictionary.length`

Comment: and you need a better `compare` function.

Comment: After I add dictionary.data, it still throws segmentation fault. How to improve my compare function? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger to see what is causing the segmentation fault?  It would also be nice if you could edit your question and include a minimal compilable example.

Comment: I'm in C newbie and I'm not using any debugger yet. Could you be more specific about compilable example?

Comment: There are a number of good cheat-sheets and tutorials (e.g. [**gdb Command Cheatsheet**](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html)). If you are going to program in C it is **critical** that you make friends with `gdb`. Go ahead, pay the price of admission, and spend several hours learning `gdb`. It will **save** you thousands of hours in the long run...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: The best advice I wish I was given when I had to learn C in university.  I was reluctant to learn GDB for the first few weeks and when I finally forced myself to learn it I saved myself hours of headaches.

Comment: Thank you for your types. So could you please help me, how to solve it? Dictionary length is max length of dictionary, index is actual size

Comment: Why are you trying to write stuff that is more complex than 'Hello World' without a debugger or debugging skills?  If every noob did that, SO would be flooded with posts asking for debugging services... Oh wait!

Comment: @JanKožušník: Perhaps your strings are not null terminated? Like I said it's very hard without a minimal example that I can actually compile and run.

Answer (score 0):

You should sort your Word-list of your Dictionary and not your Dictionary. If length is the number of all elements in your Word-list, you should use:

```
qsort(dictionary.data, dictionary.length, sizeof (dictionary.data[0]), compare);
```

and, you are right, your compare function is wrong, eg.

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) 
{ 
  const Word *x = a, *y =b;
  return strcmp (x->data,y->data); /* if data always contains a C string */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But however I edit it, it still throws me segmentation fault

Comment: Sorry, you were right. You just were probably confused about index and length. After I rewrite length to index, it works. Thank you!